# Problema con serialización XML en Java

Tags: java, xml

No consigo llevar a cabo la serialización de objetos a un fichero de tipo XML en java. Tengo una clase vivienda en la que implemento el método `XMLSerialization`.

**Clase Vivienda**

```
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Vivienda implements Serializable{
    private double metrosTotales;
    private double emisionesCo2;
    private String zonaVivienda;
    
   
    public Vivienda( String zonaVivienda, double  metrosTotales, double emisionesCo2){
          this.metrosTotales=metrosTotales;
          this.emisionesCo2=emisionesCo2;
          this.zonaVivienda=zonaVivienda;
    }
   
    public double getMetrosTotales(){
        return this.metrosTotales;
    }
   
    public double getEmisionesCo2(){
        return this.emisionesCo2;
    }
    
    public void XMLSerialization(String nomFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nomFile);
        XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(fos);
        encoder.writeObject(this);
        encoder.close();
        fos.close();
        
    }
}
```

Dentro de la clase principal, creo un nuevo objeto de tipo vivienda y lo serializo llamando al método de la clase

**Clase principal**

```java
Vivienda viv1 = new Vivienda("centro", 500, 13.6);
viv1.XMLSerialization("registro.xml");
```

El problema es que se crea el fichero "registro.xml", pero está vacío, no contiene ninguna información con respecto al objeto.

**registro.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="20.0.1" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
</java>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que implementar un constructor default y los métodos para asignar valores a los miembros:

```
public class Vivienda implements Serializable{
    private double metrosTotales;
    private double emisionesCo2;
    private String zonaVivienda;

    public Vivienda() {}

    public Vivienda(String zonaVivienda, double  metrosTotales, double emisionesCo2){
        this.metrosTotales=metrosTotales;
        this.emisionesCo2=emisionesCo2;
        this.zonaVivienda=zonaVivienda;
    }

    public double getMetrosTotales(){
        return this.metrosTotales;
    }

    public void setMetrosTotales(double metrosTotales) {
        this.metrosTotales = metrosTotales;
    }

    public double getEmisionesCo2(){
        return this.emisionesCo2;
    }

    public void setEmisionesCo2(double emisionesCo2) {
        this.emisionesCo2 = emisionesCo2;
    }

    public String getZonaVivienda() {
        return zonaVivienda;
    }

    public void setZonaVivienda(String zonaVivienda) {
        this.zonaVivienda = zonaVivienda;
    }

    public void XMLSerialization(String nomFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nomFile);
        XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(fos);
        encoder.writeObject(this);
        encoder.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Esto se requiere para un objeto JavaBeans, por lo menos como yo lo entiendo.

El resultado entonces es

```
<java version="1.8.0_372" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="org.example.Vivienda">
  <void property="emisionesCo2">
   <double>13.6</double>
  </void>
  <void property="metrosTotales">
   <double>500.0</double>
  </void>
  <void property="zonaVivienda">
   <string>centro</string>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

Comment: Gracias. ¿Habría alguna manera de crear varios objetos y serializarlos en el mismo fichero? Pues he hecho algunas pruebas y serializa sin problemas, pero reescribe el fichero cada vez y solo queda registrado el ultimo objeto serializado.

Comment: @SrAlexHrb, supongo que necesitas crear una clase con propriedades de tipo collección o Array de los otros objetos, entonces puedes serializar el objecto que contiene todos los otros como Array o collección.